# jquery validation plugin select element not being validated

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), and it's working on most everything except 2 select boxes. I've created a fiddle here to demonstrate one of these troublesome select boxes: http://jsfiddle.net/tucsonlabs/mQJCX/

If you leave the month blank and submit the form there's no error message generated even though the element has a class of required.

Comment: i Think your plugin is using name to validate the elements .both selection box have same name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used same name for the *day* and *month* field, so the plugin validated the first instance only. If you change the name of any one field, it will function normally.